# is it possible to add css styles only appear for specific browsers

Tags: html, css

Is it at all possible to assign css styles to only display in sepcific browsers? I know IE can be but Im meaning safari and google chrome? The problem is I have currently set some CSS styles to my site which looks great in firefox but seems to look totally ugly in safari and chrome and I'd really like to change that if possible

Comment: Having something that works in FF but not in Chrome and Safari usually means you're doing something wrong. Rather than go for conditional CSS, you should look for a solution that works in all browsers.

Comment: Could you be specific? Which styles?

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006568/browser-specific-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that you probably should fix your CSS and HTML. Chrome and FF should render the same generally. 
Make sure your HTML validates.

However, if you are in a pinch -- this script works great: http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

Comment: "Make sure your HTML validates." -- validation absolutely does NOT matter at all. Make sure it works everywhere. Browsers don't care about "valid HTML".

Comment: @Rudie I disagree. Validating HTML is a good step in the direction of browser interoperability. Don't have errors in your HTML, period. Different browsers respond differently to errors!

Comment: If you use invalid HTML, you're introducing undefined behaviour. It might work *now*, but there's absolutely no guarantee it'll work for the next version of any particular browser. By sticking to the standards you've got a much higher guarantee of operability.

Comment: Browsers don't care about "valid HTML" at all. It's not a matter of opinion. Ofcourse it's good to be valid, but don't make it a point, because it simply doesn't matter. This is pretty much the HTML5 idea. You know how they made the HTML5 validator (which isn't even 'done')? By seeing what works. The charset meta tag? That's not valid, but HTML5 says it is. Why? Well, you know now. Valid HTML shouldn't be a goal. Ever. It's useless and time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

Some CSS3 properties are with the prefix -moz, -webkit, -ms. Other than that it's only possible to detect the user browser version, type and then serve the different css sheet accordingly. Remember, a stylesheet does not necessarily have to have a .css extension, so you could write a PHP script that prints out different CSS for different browsers when included.

Wouldn't recommend it, though. You should simply fix your CSS, before relying on browser detection.