# Different Colour for Different Browser

Tags: css

Is there a way currently to set the colour of text, depending on the browser you are using.

As far as I know, there is no such thing as `-moz-color:` and so on so that's a no go. Only reason I need this is because `-webkit-background-clip:` is not working as it should on any site so I want to change the colour depending on the browser.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can try detecting the browser using some library like in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006568/browser-specific-css, then setting up the classes for the elements accordingly.

Comment: jQuery.browser is however removed in jQuery 1.9

Comment: without any library, you can also detect the browser using pure javascript based on the difference in **prefixes**, however it's really some kind of hack, it requires a good understanding about the browser-specific prefixes, which versions still support them, ... I'm sure if you search more on this, you will have a beautiful solution.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/)

If you are using jQuery 1.9+, you can use the **Migrate** plugin and use the function. If not, you can use it with no problem.

Other methods include CSS3 such as this one:

```
  .transparent {
      /* IE >= 9, Firefox >= 0.9, Safari >= 2, Chrome, Opera >= 9 */
      opacity: 0.5;
  }
```

and this Javascript:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      if ( navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")>0 )
      {
          // run custom code for Internet Explorer.
      }
  </script>
```

or even [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Vendor prefixes ('-moz', '-webkit' &c.) are generally for things that aren't quite finalized yet.  I can't think of a way to do this using only CSS, but you could use some Javascript to detect the browser and set the color explicitily.

Quirksmode is recommending [WhichBrowser](http://whichbrowser.net/) to detect which browser you're running on, but I haven't tried it.